# UX Stack Exchange Top User Swag

Tags: discussion

As a thank you for *being awesome*, if you have at least 1,125 reputation and are on page 1 or page 2 of …

https://ux.stackexchange.com/users?tab=reputation&filter=all

… we'll be sending you a little care package shortly:

- UX Stack Exchange t-shirt in your size
- UX Stack Exchange die-cut, vinyl stickers
- UX Stack Exchange sketch pad
- [Stack Exchange sharpie](http://shop.stackexchange.com/collections/frontpage/products/stack-exchange-sharpies)
- [Stack Exchange pen](http://shop.stackexchange.com/products/stack-exchange-pens)
- [Stack Exchange stickers](http://shop.stackexchange.com/products/stack-exchange-network-stickers)

You can expect to get an email soon with details on how to confirm and provide your mailing address and size preferences.

### The t-shirt

[image: ux.stackexchange.com Tshirt]

### The sticker

[image: ux.stackexchange.com sticker]

### The sketch pad

*(5" by 8" Moleskin type journal, with pockets on the inside back cover, elastic closure and ribbon book mark.  Sheets have horizontal lines.)*
[image: ux.stackexchange.com sketch pad]

The rest of the items you can view in the [Stack Exchange store](http://shop.stackexchange.com) — direct links to [sharpie](http://shop.stackexchange.com/collections/frontpage/products/stack-exchange-sharpies), [pens](http://shop.stackexchange.com/products/stack-exchange-pens), [stickers](http://shop.stackexchange.com/products/stack-exchange-network-stickers).

Congratulations!

<sub>(for anyone else who wants this swag, but isn't on page 1 or page 2 of the all time top users -- the limited edition t-shirts and stickers will be available for purchase from the store as soon as we're able)</sub>

Comment: This is fantastic! How lucky are we?!

Comment: Yaaay! Thanks guys!

Comment: Wow! Fab - thank you!

Comment: :)) first swag I'm genuinely interested in using

Comment: Awesome thanks!

Comment: Yaaayyy! You know the way to a geek's heart! :)

Comment: Whoa. This is seriously cool. Thank you!

Comment: Very cool, thank you!

Comment: Yeeeeehaaa, thank you very much! :)

Comment: Fantastic news! Thank you!

Comment: Ooh, free loot?! Cheers!

Comment: W00t. Sorry, is that too geeky?

Comment: Party hard! Cool.

Comment: Another one to add to my collection ;)

Comment: Wow, Thanks!! How cool is that!

Comment: Wow, cool!  (When I saw the email my reaction was "wait, what? *I'm* a top user?  How'd that happen?")

Comment: This is awesome, that is very kind. Very classy UXSE!

Comment: Thanks so much!

Comment: juuuuuust made the cut.  So glad I procrastinated so much last month!

Comment: Brilliant ! Thanks !  (the total unexpectedness of this makes it particularly good)

Comment: update: we're shipping the swag packages this week.

Comment: update: the swag packages containing tshirt/stickers/minicards have been mailed out. The notepads just got ready, we're shipping them off separately this week.

Comment: I received the t-shirt, stickers, and mini-cards today.  Thanks!

Comment: @Jin Got my t-shirt, stickers, and mini-cards. Thanks! There was no die-cut UX.SE sticker, though, is that coming separately too? Also, if we want more mini cards (for instance, to give out at a conference), is there a path to get those?

Comment: @DanielNewman I don't know why you didn't receive the UX.SE stickers. They were supposed to be mailed with the other items in the first package. I'll let our warehouse know and resend them to you(and some more minicards). I'll be creating a meta post soon on instructing how users can request for site minicards.

Comment: Got the sketch pad today. Looks awesome. Are the pen/sharpie still coming?

Comment: @Jin Thanks! As Charles mentioned, the pen and sharpie were also nowhere to be found, although I'm not one to look a gift horse in the mouth.

Comment: @CharlesBoyung weird... they should've been included. I'll check with our fulfillment company.

Comment: I agree totally with @DanielNewman - not complaining at all. Just letting you guys know what's up.

Comment: @igor: Knowing ex-USSR postal services, it could have gotten "lost" in transit or just delayed in customs clearing.

Comment: anyway unfair show, no sense to trust so people.

Comment: I'd love it if these ever made it in the store, would be awesome.

Comment: @dnbrv postal serv works perfectly (checked many times).

Comment: Those sketch pads look rather clever, could you let me know where you ordered them? I have a conference coming up and those might make fine speaker gifts

Comment: Since the store is no more, could you please remove that paragraph (and have the pages linked to say so)?

Answer (score 4):

I totally appreciate this. Something to spice up the community

Answer (score 1):

My package arrived today.

But there's only the WONDERFUL sketchpad in it. Will you send other things separately?

Thank you!

...because maybe other things were lost by the post :S

Comment: Yes. T-shirt & stickers were sent separately, and the fulfillment center forgot pens.

Comment: Thank you for the info! :)

Comment: @dnbrv - I miss the pens. Can someone be given a slap please?

Answer (score 1):

I got the T-Shirt today with A sticker, Letter and Sketchpad too

Answer (score 1):

Still didn't get anything.. And a couple emails about this to Rebecca went unanswered. Very bummed :(

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking about this today. Any update?

Comment: We got emails on 18th Jan to fill in a form and which suggested it may take 6 to 8 weeks to get mailed out.

Comment: Ah, thanks @RogerAttrill I must have forgotten. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm..still I have not got anything. :(

Answer (score 0):

I'm on page two now, doing this again :-)